# Rebuilding a Raid 1

Tags: linux, centos, dmraid

I'm trying to rebuild a raid 1 (dmraid+isw) unsuccessfully. I replaced the failed disk with a new one and the BIOS added it automatically to the raid.
Running kernel 2.6.18-194.17.4.el5.

*dmraid -r*

```
/dev/sda: isw, "isw_babcjifefe", GROUP, ok, 1953525165 sectors, data@ 0
/dev/sdb: isw, "isw_babcjifefe", GROUP, ok, 1953525165 sectors, data@ 0
```

*dmraid -s*

```
*** Group superset isw_babcjifefe
--> Subset
name   : isw_babcjifefe_Raid0
size   : 1953519616
stride : 128
type   : mirror
status : nosync
subsets: 0
devs   : 2
spares : 0
```

When i try to start the raid i receive the next errors

*dmraid -f isw -S -M /dev/sdb*

```
ERROR: isw: SPARE disk must use all space on the disk
```

*dmraid -tay*

```
isw_babcjifefe_Raid0: 0 1953519616 mirror core 3 131072 sync block_on_error 2 /dev/sda 0 /dev/sdb 0
```

*dmraid -ay*

```
RAID set "isw_babcjifefe_Raid0" was not activated
ERROR: device "isw_babcjifefe_Raid0" could not be found
```

*dmraid -f isw -S -M /dev/sdb*

```
ERROR: isw: SPARE disk must use all space on the disk
```

*dmraid -R isw_babcjifefe_Raid0 /dev/sdb*

```
ERROR: disk /dev/sdb cannot be used to rebuilding
```

*dmesg*

```
device-mapper: table: 253:13: mirror: Device lookup failure
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
device-mapper: table: 253:13: mirror: Device lookup failure
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
device-mapper: table: 253:13: mirror: Device lookup failure
device-mapper: ioctl: error adding target to table
device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
device-mapper: ioctl: device doesn't appear to be in the dev hash table.
```

Disks:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
```

LVM:

```
PV /dev/sda5   VG storage   lvm2 [914.64 GB / 28.64 GB free]
Total: 1 [914.64 GB] / in use: 1 [914.64 GB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]
Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
Found volume group "storage" using metadata type lvm2
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/home' [68.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/home2' [68.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/home3' [68.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/home4' [68.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/home5' [68.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/var' [15.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/mysql' [20.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/pgsql' [7.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/exim' [12.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/apache' [25.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/tmp' [2.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/backup' [450.00 GB] inherit
ACTIVE            '/dev/storage/log' [15.00 GB] inherit
```

Comment: I hope you have backups; scrap the fakeraid and use (reliable, robust, proven) software raid with mdadm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to agree with Andrew.

Hopefully you can do a mount -o ro /dev/sd

Then, copy the data off of that drive and start over using mdadm and full, reliable, easy to use, fast software raid.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure dmraid supports rebuilding a fakeraid (like isw). I would advise scraping the isw and build pure software raid with mdadm.